# How to add Glassfish 6.0 server in Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java Developers 2020-12 version

Tags: java, eclipse, glassfish

I've an old project which i'm trying to port on latest glassfish 6.0 version. I'm using 'Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java Developers 2020-12' and unable to finad a way to add glassfish 6.0 server inside IDE. I'm seeing only upto Glassfish 5.1.0 are supported.

Downloaded Glassfish 6.0.0 from https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/ee4j.glassfish/downloads
Glassfish eclipse tool from https://download.eclipse.org/glassfish-tools/1.0.1/gf-tools-repository-1.0.1.201904090220.zip

Is Glassfish 6.0.0 not yet supported in Eclipse IDE?

[Eclipse glasshfish server][1].
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9TBv2.png

Answer (score 1):

If you want to start Glassfish from Eclipse IDE, you can do it through Payara Tools,

[image]

[image]

Although the plugin recognizes it as a payara, no problem you can start and stop the server.